# Writing SQL query in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am new to Laravel and finding it a bit hard to learn it. I am having trouble in writing an SQL query that involves joining between multiple tables. I viewed the documentations but it did not understand how to write it.

This is my raw sql query which I want to write in Laravel style:

```
SELECT 
cd.`company_details`,cd.`company_id`,cd.`company_logo`,cd.`company_name`,
cd.`company_type_id`,cd.`company_website`,cd.`login_email`,cd.`phone_number,                   ld.`date_created`,ld.`is_active`,ld.`login_password`,ld.`login_type`
FROM `company_details` AS cd
JOIN `login_details` AS ld
ON cd.`login_email`=ld.`login_email`
WHERE cd.`login_email`=$login_email
AND cd.`company_id`=$company_id
AND cd.`company_name`=$company_name 
AND ld.`login_type`='COMPANY'
```

I know the basic syntac like DB::tablename()->select()->where()->get() but can't write the query. Please Help.

Answer (score 2):

```
 DB::table('company_details AS cd')
  ->join('company_details AS ld', 'ld.login_email', '=', 'cd.login_email')
  ->where('cd.login_email', $login_email)
  ->where('cd.company_id', $company_id)
  ->where('cd.company_name', $company_name)
  ->where('ld.login_type', 'COMPANY')
  ->select('cd.company_details, cd.company_id, cd.company_logo, cd.company_name, cd.company_type_id, cd.company_website, cd.login_email, cd.phone_number')
->get();
```

For joining multiple tables read this documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins